# How to remove item from an array in PowerShell (v5.1)

Tags: powershell

I have an array of elements in PowerShell (v5.1) as below.

**I want to remove the item with matching condition EmpId=102**

```
$testData = @(
   @{ Name='ABC'; EmpId=100  },
   @{ Name='EFG'; EmpId=101 },
   @{ Name='XYZ'; EmpId=102 }
);
```

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

maybe something like `$testData.Remove($testData.Find("EmpId == 102"))` ?

Comment: is your actual array filled with _hashtable items_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your array is really a collection of one-item hashtables, then the following otta work ... [*grin*] it pipes the collection thru the `Where-Object` cmdlet & filters out anything item that has the value-to-exclude in the `EmpId` key value.

```
$TestData = @(
    @{ Name='ABC'; EmpId=100  }
    @{ Name='EFG'; EmpId=101 }
    @{ Name='XYZ'; EmpId=102 }
    )
$EmpId_ToExclude = 102

$TestData |
    Where-Object {
        $_['EmpId'] -ne $EmpId_ToExclude
        }
```

output ...

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
EmpId                          100
Name                           ABC
EmpId                          101
Name                           EFG
```

note that the items are not *required* to be in order ... that is how hashtables work if you don't specify `[ordered]`.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this info is some use.  Maybe you can use an arraylist.  You don't need `@( )` to make an array.

```
[collections.arraylist]$testData = @{ Name='ABC'; EmpId=100  },
  @{ Name='EFG'; EmpId=101 },
  @{ Name='XYZ'; EmpId=102 }

$a = $testdata[1]
$testdata.remove($a)
```

Or

```
$testdata.removeat(1)
```

Unfortunely, this doesn't work.  I guess you would need a pointer to the hashtable:

```
$testdata.remove(@{ Name='XYZ'; EmpId=102 })
```

Actually, it would be easy with a single hashtable:

```
$testData = @{ 'ABC'=100  
  'EFG'=101
  'XYZ'=102 }

$testdata.remove('xyz')

$testdata

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ABC                            100
EFG                            101
```